# Do I have to keep subscribing to get messages in PubNub?

Tags: pubnub

I am new to PubNub API and according to the example in PubNub C++ SDK, I have to put subscribing inside a loop to get messages continuously.

```
// Sync
void subscribe(pubnub::context &pn) {
  enum pubnub_res res;

  for (;;) {
    res = pn.subscribe("my_channel").await();

    if (PNR_OK == res) {
      std::vector<std::string> msg = pn.get_all();

      for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = msg.begin(); it != msg.end(); ++it) {
       std::cout << *it << std::endl;
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Request failed" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

It does not make much sense to me. Usually we just need to subscribe to something once then we can keep getting messages? In my use case, I also confirmed I have to subscribe to my channel, get a message, then subscribe to the channel again to get the next message. To keep getting messages, I have to keep subscribing. But then what about those messages arriving between my subscriptions? Will they get lost?

I am quite confused... Thanks so much for any help!

Tao

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub C SDK Subscribe

[PubNub C/C++ SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-c/pubnub-c-sdk) is different than the other SDKs just due to the nature of how those languages work. You subscribe, you get an immediate success and then you subscribe again. When a message is received, you subscribe again. If no message is received by the end of the subscribe timeout (about 5 minutes), you subscribe again. This is how all other SDKs work but they do it automatically.

A code snippet here but more at the above SDK docs link.

```c
pubnub_subscribe(ctx, "my_channel", NULL);
pbresult = pubnub_await(ctx);
if (PNR_OK == pbresult) {
    char const *message = pubnub_get(ctx);
    while (message != NULL) {
        message = pubnub_get(ctx);
    }
}
```